# Storyboard add a custom view which has xib file has no subviews

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, loadnibnamed

I create a custom `UIView` A with a xib file and it can be loaded correctly by:

```
    NSArray *starsNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"nibName" owner:nil options:nil];
    A *starsView = starsNib[0];
    [self.view addSubview:starsView];
```

Then in my storyboard file, I add this custom view A to the `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`. When the tableview is loading, I find the custom view A has no subviews which are added in the xib file. I also find when the A's `initWithCoder:` returns, it has no child views.
BTW, in the xib file, I have set both the `parent view` and `file's owner` to the custom view A class.
I'd like to know why this happens and why the subviews are not loaded when `initWithCoder:` returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the view is being loaded from the storyboard, not the XIB. And in the storyboard the view is empty.

You should remove the view from the storyboard and load it in code, probably when the cell is instantiated as it only needs to be done once per cell.

Comment: ah~I forgot the `initWithCoder: ` can also be invoked by SB.  However, Besides "loading in code" I still wonder is there any way to implement this?

Comment: IIRC you can only import a controller into the storyboard, not a view, though it isn't something I do so I don't remember exactly...

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom tableViewCell using Xib which has the file owner your custom  UITableViewCell class and then you can use `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray * starsNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"nibName" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = starsNib[0];
    }
    return cell;
}
```